# Joken.verify(token, secret) is returning invalid signature

Tags: elixir

I am using elixir with phoenix. When I make request by browser it verified the signature as expected but when I am trying with test case it returns invalid signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the solution I was encoding `:crypto.hash(:sha256, "#{Rails.shared_secret()} #{company.api_secret}")` to base64. It works fine when I passed it to `Joken.Signer.create("HS512", secret)` without encoding.
thanks

Comment: If this answers your question, go ahead and mark it as the solution.